# Taking Mean of list of numbers having positive, negative, NaN, zero values and only taking mean of positive numbers only

Tags: mean

How to take mean of positive numbers only in the series or in dataframe?

How to take mean of positive numbers only in the series or in dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this :

```
def mean_positive(L):
    # Get all positive numbers into another list
    pos_only = [x for x in L if x > 0]
    if pos_only:
        return sum(pos_only) /  len(pos_only)
    raise ValueError('No postive numbers in input')
```